# How to play drums on keyboard?

Tags: drums, keyboard, drum-kits

I have  a yamaha i455 and I have drum kits on that and i wanted to get some notations like  C D E F, you know like play this sequence and this sequences I wanted to get some atleast 50 of them so that I can play them on my keyboard as i do not have a drummer, but i have a guitarist. Please help me with some sites. I searched a lot but did not find any and this question is the last resort. Example I went to musescore but did not get much help. I went to soundsnap but I cannot just listen there and figure out which is this sound and what. Please help.

I am not ok enough to read sheets but i do not know if drums are also written on Sheets.? Anyway you know what to say. I have i455 yamaha.

Thanks!

Comment: I've never seen drum notation written the way you are looking for it. What you have to do is learn which notes on the keyboard play which pieces of the drum kit, and then learn standard drum notation. That might sound hard but it's not that bad, partly because there are only about ten main kit pieces that you have to learn to play and the notation for and that's it. It's not like 88 different piano keys.

Comment: Could you help me a little bit more so that i can get started!

Answer (score 1):

What you basically have is different keys of your keyboard producing sounds of the different parts of a drum kit like Kick, Snare, toms, Hat, Crash, ride, etc. If you blatantly ask for drum notations, people will give you notations that drummers look at while playing a drum kit. To play a drum kit from your keyboard, you firsrly need an understanding of how drums are played. Then, after figuring out which keyboard key produces what drum sound, you have to make up patterns yourself and play. Basically you'd be playing the keyboard but producing drum sounds. People who're not closely acquainted with digital keyboards won't umderstand it. Unless you understand drums, you won't be able to do what you are trying to do. Plus no one is going to provide you notations for this thing. You have to figure it out yourself. I have also (self) learned drums and I do play drums on the keyboard to create backing tracks for my videos.

Watch this video:
[**Tutorial: How to Keyboard Drum**](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=WwnkWjrdhLM). This is all you need to get started.